# Reading different data from the same COM Port

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I am working with 2 linear stages that operate via COM Port. These stages have their own syntax; a command like 1MVR5 would make axis 1 move of 5mm.
I have successfully developed a GUI in VB.net which let a user operate with the 2 axis.

I want to add a feature, a real time positioning of the axis. (they can travel from 0 to 100 mm)
so if a user inserts 10 in the position textbox and presses MOVE, the axis will start moving of 10mm and another textbox will constantly refresh the position of the axis.

Problem: every time an axis moves, a function waitForStop is called, which constantly polls the axis by sending a command which returns a statusByte, if the 3d bit is == 1, then the axis is moving, if it is 0 the axis has stopped.
At the same time to poll the position of the axis another command must be sent, which returns the position of the axis.
The problem here is that i have 2 different streams of information on the same COM port.
Is there a way of "splitting" the informations in any way?
I'm pretty sure there is a solution becuase i have already worked with more professional stages which provided SDK that could do this thing (sampe COM port, both WaitForStop and RefreshPos working simoultaneously)

Comment: That would depend on how the stages work. If they are capable of accepting and handling multiple commands at once, you could break the commander and interrogator into different  threads.... But it is all mute if the stages won't handle it.

Comment: Just use a variable to remember which command you sent.  Another one to remember for which axis you sent the command, you should already have that.

Comment: The problem is not to remember which command has been sent, but to be able to write a command to the port while the port is already sending data continously. I think Trevor provided the right answer. The Controllers attached to the stages can't handle this kind of data transmission

Comment: The problem is probably because waitForStop is taking over the channel. You probably should check if you can manually poll for the status and therefore do the 2 polling commands interleaved.

Comment: I can't, because as you said WaitForStop continues to poll the statusByte until the movement bit (3rd) becomes 0, meaning the stage has stopped. but this continuos dataStream prevents another write command to the COM port. (if I do so, the statusByte messes up and the 3d bit will never go to 0 even if the stage halted)